# Get variables value using another variables values

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, currency

this is the code,and afterwards it will be written what I need your help with:

```js
function Vars() {
  var select1 = document.getElementById('From');
  var From = (select1.options[select.selectedIndex]);
  var select2 = document.getElementById('To');
  var To = (select2.options[select.selectedIndex]);
}

function calculate() {
  $.getJSON(
    "http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD",
    function(data) {
      var ZER = 0
      var USD = 1
      var AUD = data.rates.AUD
      var BRL = data.rates.BRL
      var BGN = data.rates.BGN
      var CAD = data.rates.CAD
      var CNY = data.rates.CNY
      var HRK = data.rates.HRK
      var CZK = data.rates.CZK
      var DKK = data.rates.DKK
      var EUR = data.rates.EUR
      var HKD = data.rates.HKD
      var HUF = data.rates.HUF
      var INR = data.rates.INR
      var IDR = data.rates.IDR
      var ILS = data.rates.ILS
      var KRW = data.rates.KRW
      var MYR = data.rates.MYR
      var MXN = data.rates.MXN
      var NZD = data.rates.NZD
      var NOK = data.rates.NOK
      var JPY = data.rates.JPY
      var PLN = data.rates.PLN
      var RON = data.rates.RON
      var RUB = data.rates.RUB
      var ZAR = data.rates.ZAR
      var SEK = data.rates.SEK
      var THB = data.rates.THB
      var TRY = data.rates.TRY
      var GBP = data.rates.GBP
      alert(To.value / From.value)
    })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <center>
    <a href="index.html">
      <img id="logo" src="http://placehold.it/340x170" height="170px" width="340px">
    </a>
    <div id="converter">
      <center>
        <article>
          <br>
          <input type="number" name="amount" placeholder="Amount" id="amount" />
          <br>
          <br>
          <select id="From">
            <option value="ZER">Convert From..</option>
            <option value="USD">US Dollar</option>
            <option value="AUD">Australian Dollar</option>
            <option value="BRL">Brazilian Real</option>
            <option value="BGN">Bulgarian Lev</option>
            <option value="CAD">Canadian Dollar</option>
            <option value="CNY">Chinese Yuan Renminbi</option>
            <option value="HRK">Croatian Kuna</option>
            <option value="CZK">Czech Koruna</option>
            <option value="DKK">Danish Krone</option>
            <option value="EUR">Euro</option>
            <option value="HKD">Hong Kong Dollar</option>
            <option value="HUF">Hungarian Forint</option>
            <option value="INR">Indian Rupee</option>
            <option value="IDR">Indonesian Rupiah</option>
            <option value="ILS">Israeli Shekel</option>
            <option value="KRW">South Korean Won</option>
            <option value="MYR">Malaysian Ringgit</option>
            <option value="MXN">Mexican Peso</option>
            <option value="NZD">New Zealand Dollar</option>
            <option value="NOK">Norwegian Krone</option>
            <option value="JPY">Japanese Yen</option>
            <option value="PLN">Polish Zloty</option>
            <option value="RON">Romanian New Leu</option>
            <option value="RUB">Russian Ruble</option>
            <option value="ZAR">South African Rand</option>
            <option value="SEK">Swedish Krona</option>
            <option value="THB">Thai Baht</option>
            <option value="TRY">Turkish Lira</option>
            <option value="GBP">British Pound</option>
          </select>
          <div id="to">&nbsp;To&nbsp;</div>
          <select id="To">
            <option value="ZER">Convert To..</option>
            <option value="USD">US Dollar</option>
            <option value="AUD">Australian Dollar</option>
            <option value="BRL">Brazilian Real</option>
            <option value="BGN">Bulgarian Lev</option>
            <option value="CAD">Canadian Dollar</option>
            <option value="CNY">Chinese Yuan Renminbi</option>
            <option value="HRK">Croatian Kuna</option>
            <option value="CZK">Czech Koruna</option>
            <option value="DKK">Danish Krone</option>
            <option value="EUR">Euro</option>
            <option value="HKD">Hong Kong Dollar</option>
            <option value="HUF">Hungarian Forint</option>
            <option value="INR">Indian Rupee</option>
            <option value="IDR">Indonesian Rupiah</option>
            <option value="ILS">Israeli Shekel</option>
            <option value="KRW">South Korean Won</option>
            <option value="MYR">Malaysian Ringgit</option>
            <option value="MXN">Mexican Peso</option>
            <option value="NZD">New Zealand Dollar</option>
            <option value="NOK">Norwegian Krone</option>
            <option value="JPY">Japanese Yen</option>
            <option value="PLN">Polish Zloty</option>
            <option value="RON">Romanian New Leu</option>
            <option value="RUB">Russian Ruble</option>
            <option value="ZAR">South African Rand</option>
            <option value="SEK">Swedish Krona</option>
            <option value="THB">Thai Baht</option>
            <option value="TRY">Turkish Lira</option>
            <option value="GBP">British Pound</option>
          </select>
          <br>
          <br>
          <button type="click" id="submit" onclick=" Vars; calculate(); ">Convert!</button>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
        </article>
      </center>
    </div>
```

I need to get the value of the variable that the From/To.value contains its name and I don't know how to do it. 
Appreciate it. (please do not give me notes about the code I know it's not the most officient code but I need your help just in this specific problem and I'll fix all that stuff later.)

Comment: Your variables are defined to a local block scope..... They can only be accessed inside of Vars()...

Comment: Well there is no actual way to do it right now. The variables need to be shared either by passing them in or by making them global. The former is preferred, of course.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. can you please send an example?

Comment: Oh. this isn't ny code. someone edited it.. I'll send the original in a moment EDIT: it is my code.

Comment: @epascarello but if I write the from.value alone in the alert section, it shows the value..

Comment: because you are alerting directly from the element....

Comment: No man, I alert from another function and it works

Answer (score 0):

First with this code `<button type="click" id="submit" onclick=" Vars; calculate(); ">` it never calls the method `Vars`, it is just a reference to it. Without the `()` it is not going to be called.

Next look at

```
function Vars() {
  var select1 = document.getElementById('From');  
  var From = (select1.options[select.selectedIndex]); <--var 
  var select2 = document.getElementById('To');
  var To = (select2.options[select.selectedIndex]); <--var 
}
```

Those vars make the variable only reference to the block scope of the method Vars. You can not access them outside of the method. So that is why you will not be able to use `From` or `To` inside of `calculate`. For that to happen, you would have to make them global.

Next, you are referencing an unknown variable `select`, that is an error from when you copied and pasted the original code.

```
var From = (select1.options[select.selectedIndex]); <-- what is select?
var To = (select2.options[select.selectedIndex]);   <-- what is select?
```

Next issue is once you get that fixed, you are diving two strings.

```
alert(To.value / From.value)
```

The string value does not magically reference the variables you created above it. You would need to look that up. And with that it would be bracket notation. But there is no need to look up the one value since the From would always be one.

---

So what should your code look like?

```
function calculate() {

  var select1 = document.getElementById('From'),
      fromCode = select1.options[select1.selectedIndex].value, 
      select2 = document.getElementById('To'),
      toCode = select2.options[select.selectedIndex].value,
      fromAmt = document.getElementById("amount");

  $.getJSON(
    "http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=" + fromCode,
    function(data) {
      var toRate = data.rates[toCode];      
      alert(fromAmt * toRate);
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your From and To variables seems to be declared inside of the Vars function, which means they cannot be accessed in the calculate function;

You can declare them outside of the Vars function in order to use them in other function.

```
var From;
var To;
        function Vars() {
      var select1 = document.getElementById('From');
      From = (select1.options[select.selectedIndex]);
      var select2 = document.getElementById('To');
      To = (select2.options[select.selectedIndex]);
    }

function calculate() {
  $.getJSON(
    "http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD",
    function(data) {
      var ZER = 0
      var USD = 1
      var AUD = data.rates.AUD
      var BRL = data.rates.BRL
      var TRY = data.rates.TRY
      var GBP = data.rates.GBP
      alert(To.value / From.value)
    })
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: you mean to don't put then in any function?

Comment: yes, declare them in a global way in order to be able to use them where ever you want

Comment: and it still doesn't let me to access the variables value using the From and To

Comment: Your solution only dealt with one of many many errors in the code.